# Having troubles wrapping text to align with image using only flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to wrap text under an image using flexbox only, i have tried almost everything i can come up with, using flex-grow, flex-basis, flex-shrink. I've put all of the text and image into their own seperate div classes but still that didn't seem to help. The image is aligned with the text but the text won't wrap, the only way i got the image to align with the text is by using "text-align" im not sure why or how text align moved an IMAGE but it did.

````
**HTML:**```<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Information</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="title">Information!</div>

    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="flex-wrap">

        <img src="./images/barberry.png" alt="barberry">
        <div class="text">This is a type of plant. We love this one.</div>
        
      </div>

      <div class="flex-wrap">

        <img src="./images/chilli.png" alt="chili">
    <div class="text">This is another type of plant. Isn't it nice</div>



      </div>

      <div class="flex-wrap">

        <img src="./images/pepper.png" alt="pepper">
    <div class="text">We have so many plants. Yay plants.</div>

      </div>

      <div class="flex-wrap">

        <img src="./images/saffron.png" alt="saffron">
    <div class="text">I'm running out of things to say about plants.</div>


      </div>
   

    
    

    
    </div>```
    CSS:
    ```
        body {
          font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
        }
        
        .flex-container {
          display: flex;
          flex: 1;
         justify-content: center;
         text-align: center;
         gap: 52px;
        }
        
        
        
        
        
        
        img {
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;
        }
        
        .title {
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
          padding-bottom: 32px;
          font-size: 36px;
          font-weight: 900;
        }```
````

Comment: Can you be more specific by wrap text on an image

Comment: I said wrap text "under" an image

Comment: You mean so that it does not overlap image width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text does not overlap image width, you have to set the width for the parent div separately from the image so that the text will have the same width

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-wrap {
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.flex-wrap img {
  height: 100px;
}

.flex-wrap .text {
  text-align: center;
}

.title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 32px;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">Information!</div>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-wrap">

    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="barberry">
    <div class="text">This is a type of plant. We love this one.</div>

  </div>

  <div class="flex-wrap">

    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="chili">
    <div class="text">This is another type of plant. Isn't it nice</div>

  </div>

  <div class="flex-wrap">

    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="pepper">
    <div class="text">We have so many plants. Yay plants.</div>

  </div>

  <div class="flex-wrap">

    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="saffron">
    <div class="text">I'm running out of things to say about plants.</div>

  </div>

</div>
```